# Groovyc:unexpected token: assert -- Why? (groovy 2.5.6)

Tags: groovy

I'm learning Groovy following some examples from https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Groovy/article.html, and I'm having trouble with the "assert" function because it is not recognized.
I'd search a lot about this, but found nothing, so I need your help to find out why this does not work.

This is the code and message from the IDE:

[image: groovy_assert_unexpected_token]

The same problem from command line:

[image: groovyc_assert_unexpected_token]

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

I'm re-reading the linked article, and I can see now why didn't work for me the first time: Because I copy the code into the IDE, but those examples written in this way are supposed to be executed into GroovyConsole directly.

If I copy the code into GroovyConsole, then it executes OK, but for this to work on normal code in IDEs, then must be wrapped with class and method code.

Thanks @dagget!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class contains code but you have to put code into methods of class

`def ...` - declaration of class variables and it's ok

but `assert` - is a code and must be in function:

```
class A{
    int i=1
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        assert i==2
    }
}
```

or you can skip class declaration then code above will be like this:

```
int i=1
assert i==2
```

Comment: Really THANKS! It works now.
I don't know why the examples are in this form, without the method, only as class definition.